# How to prevent a mercurial commit with no files specified (prevent commiting all modified files) using a hook

Tags: python, mercurial, mercurial-hook

I am working on a mercurial hook in python to prevent a general commit when one forget to specifies files to be commited. I commited by accident several debug modification and don't want this to happen again.

I would like to make a hook that ask for a confirmation when no files is specified in the commit command.

I got how to create the hook, how to have it called, how to prevent the commit. The one thing I cannot get is how to know if the user specified files in the commit or not.
I could use the sys.argv command but that does not satify me.

I can't find a clear mercurial.ui API that explains methods available.

Does anyone know how to get the hg command parameters?
(os.environ returns no 'HG_XXXXX' variabele :/)